# Include both the page counter and the last accessed time of the web page in one cookie.

Tags: php, cookies

How to include both the page counter and the last accessed time of the web page in one cookie? So that each time When I retrieve cookie information, it gives me both the details.

```
<?php
 $inTwoMonths=60*60*24*60+time();
 setcookie('lastVisit',date("G:i - m/d/y"),$inTwoMonths);
 if(isset($_COOKIE['lastVisit']))
 {
    $visit=$_COOKIE['lastVisit'];
    echo "Your last visit was - ".$visit;
 }
 else
     echo "You've got some stale cookies!";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is never gonna work. When setting the cookie, the actual value is not available for PHP. PHP sends the cookie to the browser along with the rest of the headers and only the next time you load the page, the cookie is send from the browser to the server and has a value retrievable for PHP.

But to answer your question:

A cookie can store an array. [See example 3 of the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

You could do something like:

```
$page_counter = 371;
$last_visit = date("G:i - m/d/y");

setcookie('lastVisit[count]',$page_counter,$inTwoMonths);
setcookie('lastVisit[visit]',$last_visit,$inTwoMonths);
```

On the next load, you can then do

```
$cookie_value=$_COOKIE['lastVisit'];
echo $cookie_value['count'];
echo $cookie_value['visit'];
```

Comment: i think this would really solve my problem buddy! let me try this.. thank ya!